# How to set default direction in JQuery widgets

Tags: jquery, right-to-left, jquery-widgets, jqxwidgets

How can I set default direction for all widgets used in JQuery widgets?
Currently I am use `rtl : true` property when I am initialize **every** widget.

```
 $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 1000,
                rtl:true,
.
.
.
```

It is redundant and if I wants to change the localization setting to RTL based location (such as Persian), I should add this property to all of widgets.

Comment: please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: can always set it using a variable. Each plugin has it's own requirements so there wouldn't be a global approach other than that

Comment: RTL as Localization property, not layouting. For example extjs has this feature by changing lib from `ext-js.js` to `ext-js-rtl.js` all direction changes to RTL: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/rtl.html